# Showing $(n-1)^2|(n^k-1)$ iff $(n-1)|k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm struggling.  I thinnk I'm close but then I get stuck.

$\Rightarrow$  Since $(n-1)^2|(n^k-1)$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $n^k-1=(n-1)^2m$  But we can rewrite $n^k$ as
$$n^k=[(n-1)+1]^k$$
Then by the binomial theorem
$$n^k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(n-1)^i=1+\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}(n-1)^i=1+(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}(n-1)^{i-1}$$
Then 
$$n^k-1=(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}(n-1)^{i-1}=(n-1)^2m$$
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}(n-1)^{i-1}=(n-1)m$$
Here's where I get stuck.  I know I can factor a $k$ out since our binomial coefficient ranges from $1$ to $k$, not $0$ to $k$ so I'd be very close to showing what i need.  But that will leave me with
$$k\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(k-1)!}{(k-i)!i!}(n-1)^{i-1}=(n-1)m$$
Perhaps there is a simpler explanation?

Comment: Have you used the given information that $(n-1) | k $?  I don't see that used anywhere in your work so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n^k-1=(n-1)(n^{k-1}+n^{k-2}\dots n+1)$ so $(n-1)^2|(n^k-1)\iff (n-1)|(1+n+n^2\dots n^{k-1})$

since $n\equiv1\bmod(n-1)$ we get $1+n+n^2\dots n^{k-1}\equiv \underbrace{1+1\dots+1}_{\text{k times}}\equiv k \bmod n-1$ so $k$ must be a multiple of $n-1$ if we want this to be dividible by $n-1$